# Retrieve value of any cell in a column by inserting row number

Tags: excel, formula

Complete newbie here, just wonder about the formula in excel to retrieve  the value of any cell in a given column by inserting its row number. Example: in a cell i insert number 5, so the cell below should have the formula that allows to display the value of the cell in E5. Or better yet, if i insert 5, i would like to have value for cell with row number "5+x". Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell in which you insert the number is A1, the formula is

```
=INDIRECT("E"&A1)
```

To answer the edited question:

```
=INDIRECT("E"&(A1+x))
```

where x could be an integer or another cell reference.

Comment: Great thank you very much Nick! What if by inserting 5 i want E6 instead of E5 to be retrieved?

Comment: Thank you again for the fast answer Nick!